# JQuery Draggable: Revert back on condition from drop function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to revert back a dragged element after being rejected in Drop. My page structure is as the following:

I have a list of football players on the right side and a football field with slots for players on the lift side. I want to enable users to drag a players from the list and drop them on the field to their slot. The list contains different type of players such as Goalkeepers, Defenders ..etc. And the field contains slots for different type of players as well. Each players type has certain slots where they can be dropped in. If a user tries to drop into a wrong slot, then the player must be reverted back.

**Draggable Code**

```
 $(".list_player_jersey img").draggable({
    addClasses: false,
    helper: "clone",
    start: function(event, ui) {
       //some code here ... 
       //assign ui to a global variable 
       //animate ui and change it's size while being dragged.
    },
    revert: function(success) {
         //change some img src 
         afterRelease();//animate ui back to it's original size while it's reverting. 
         return !success;
    },
    stop: function() {
        checkDenyClick(false);
    },
    cursor: "pointer",
    cursorAt: {"left": 25}
});
```

**Droppable Code**

```
  $(droppableItems).droppable({
            tolerance: "pointer",
            drop: function(event, ui) {
                var dropItem = $(this);
                var dragItem = $(ui.draggable);
                var data = validatePosition(dragItem, dropItem);
                if (data.status === true) {
                     //success code, continue normally from here, do other calculations
                }
                else
                {
                  // Here I want to revert back ui
                }       
             afterRelease();
            },
            accept:function (ui){
                //I don't' how to use this part                
            },
            over: function(event, ui) {
                 // adding come classes
            },
            out: function() {
                //removing some classes. 
            }
        });
```

What I tried so far is to call revert from drop function :

```
 drop: function(event, ui) {
         //..some code
          var success= false;
         if (data.status === true) {
                  //success code, continue normally from here, do other calculations
                   success= true;
                }
                else
                {
                  // revert back ui
                    success= false;
                }

       ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', function() {
            afterRelease();
            return !success;
        }
    }
```

But the problem with that is, if `success` become `true`, it will remain `true` for that particular element. In other words, if success is true it means it will not revert back right?, so I let's say Elem1 was dropped in Drop1 successfully, later,if I try to drag it again and drop it somewhere else (undroppable area) it doesn't revert back and I think it's revert value is set to false (since I overridden the function value when I called revert from drop:function) and it will not revert.

So, how do I revert back if the condition fail inside drop?

n.b I tried to use `accept`, but it seems it's being fired once I start dragging (even before hovering over the droppable area), and when I log $(this), it appears as if it loops thru all droppable elements.

Comment: can you give specific classes to your draggables and accept items according to those classes in your droppables so that it would automatically revert back if its not accepted. Please setup a fiddle with your demo code so that we can find help you better :)

Comment: I will set a fiddle soon. It seems when I try to use **accept**, **over** stops working for some reason.

Comment: exactly. if that element is not a valid drop, then its no point to indicate that it is over it. So if that element is not in the 'accept', dragging that element over the droppable wont fire the 'over' event. And accept is not supposed to be used as u r trying to. U need to pass comma seperate selectors. Read here for more info http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept

Comment: That's the thing, what I need to do is, once the dragged elem is hovering on the empty slots, I want to change their background to blue, if it's allowed, red if it's not so it become easier for the user to realized that he is trying to add a player in the wrong position. So far **over** is doing this nicely. But if I use **accept** I won't have that UI feature.

Comment: ohh. at this point i will need a working code to try something out. hav some ideas but not sure of it.